# Finishing trial early in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a thirty-day free trial of my subscription in Stripe.
I want users to have the option of paying early, at which point their remaining trial days will be added to the end of their first billing term.

If I set the subscription's trial_end and billing_cycle_anchor to the current timestamp, will the user be invoiced immediately? Or would it be best to cancel their existing subscription and create another without a trial?

Then, I guess, put the remaining trial days on to the newly created billing_cycle_anchor and prorate=false?

Thanks

Comment: I think that this particular case is described here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials#combine-trial-anchor. You would like to end the trial early, invoicing the Customer for the proration amount immediately.

Comment: If you set the trial_end and billing_cycle_anchor both to "now", the user will be Invoiced, but invoiced for the full amount of the next billing period, i.e. the full amount of the monthly Subscription cost.